# Windows Groups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a prohibition for using a Windows Group account (with users) and mapping them to a credential in SQL Server.

I was able to make this work with an Windows Login Account and I believe this will work well with SQL Accounts.

Running the following:

```
ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\GROUP_NAME] FROM WINDOWS
ADD CREDENTIAL [credentialname];  
GO
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot use parameter CREDENTIAL for a Windows login. error 15080

Answer (score 1):

Adding a credential to a Login is used to give a Windows identity to a SQL Login for interacting with external resources, typically in CLR code or Linked Servers.

> CREDENTIAL = credential_name The name of a credential to be mapped to
>   a SQL Server login. The credential must already exist in the server.
>   For more information, see Credentials. A credential cannot be mapped
>   to the sa login.

[ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

It's not intended, documented, or supported for Windows Logins of any kind, and doesn't actually work.

Comment: Thank you David, see this question is related to using SQL TDE using Azure Key Vault as the EKM, one of the steps in an Microsoft article was to run that think it needs updating.

Comment: Ok.  That's a completely separate use for the login's credential.  I'm checking internally about how that's used.

Comment: I heard back from support, and the credential can be removed from your login after TDE is configured and the credential has been added to the login created from the asymmetric key.  So there's no need to configure the credential on a group login.